# Get design-time notifications when a Control referenced in another control is removed from the Form

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, design-time

I have a custom control with a property allowing to select another control of a specific type on a form. For simplicity, let it be TextBox controls.

The property of my custom control looks like this:

```
private TextBox _targetControl;

public TextBox TargetControl
{
    get {return _targetControl;}
    set {_targetControl = value;}
}
```

Is there a way to get a notification in my custom control when the selected target control is removed from the form at design time? Note that the target control can be located in a container such as Panel (i.e. it is not an item of the form's Controls collection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To receive notifications when a Component is added, removed, renamed or otherwise changed at Design-Time, you can call the [[Component].GetService()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component.getservice) method to initialize an [IComponentChangeService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.icomponentchangeservice) on the current Site.

This Interface allows to subscribe to events, as [IComponentChangeService.ComponentRemoved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.icomponentchangeservice.componentremoved), that are raised when *something happens* to a Component in the Form Designer.

For example, when this UserControl is sited, it subscribes to the `ComponentRemoved` and `ComponentRemoving` events, to verify whether the event is related to the Control referenced by the `TargetControl` Property:

```
public partial class UCComponentsChange : UserControl {
    private IComponentChangeService componentChangeService;

    public UCComponentsChange() =>InitializeComponent();

    private TextBox _targetControl = null;
    public TextBox TargetControl {
        get => _targetControl;
        set => _targetControl = value;
    }

    public override ISite Site {
        get => base.Site;
        set {
            base.Site = value;
            RegisterComponentsChangeNotifications();
        }
    }

    private void RegisterComponentsChangeNotifications() {
        if (componentChangeService != null) {
            componentChangeService.ComponentRemoving -= NotifyComponentRemoving;
            componentChangeService.ComponentRemoved -= NotifyComponentRemoved;
        }

        componentChangeService = GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService)) as IComponentChangeService;
        if (componentChangeService != null) {
            componentChangeService.ComponentRemoving += NotifyComponentRemoving;
            componentChangeService.ComponentRemoved += NotifyComponentRemoved;
        }
    }

    private void NotifyComponentRemoving(object sender, ComponentEventArgs e) {
        if (IsTargetControlAffected(e.Component)) {
            // Our Control is being removed
        }
    }

    private void NotifyComponentRemoved(object sender, ComponentEventArgs e) {
        if (IsTargetControlAffected(e.Component)) {
            // Our Control has been removed. Set the reference to null 
            TargetControl = null;
        }
    }

    private bool IsTargetControlAffected(IComponent component) =>
        _targetControl != null && _targetControl == component;
}
```